I want to display a CMS page in Magento 2
I have a CMS page named WIB whose identifier is wib_home_page_content. I have to fetch the cms page and then using the page layout system. I am able to fetch the CMS block. But now I have to return it and render it in the frontend using the xml file. I am facing some issue with that.
Controller File:
<?php

namespace Brady\Wib\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Cms\Model\BlockRepository;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $blockRepository;
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        BlockRepository $blockRepository,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->blockRepository = $blockRepository;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            // Fetch the CMS block
            $block = $this->blockRepository->getById('wib_home_page_content'); // The block identifier
            $blockContent = $block->getContent();
    
            // Pass the content to the layout
            $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template');
            if ($block) {
                $block->setData('my_data', $blockContent);
            }
            return $resultPage;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Handle errors (e.g., block not found)
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('The CMS block could not be loaded.'));
            return $this->_redirect('noroute');
        }
    }
}

XML File:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <!-- The CMS block content will be dynamically appended here -->
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

I am not able to render the CMS block. Currently I am getting a empty page without any content. What could be the reason ?

In your controller, you're fetching the CMS block using the BlockRepository, which is correct. However, in the XML layout file, you need to add a block for rendering that CMS content.
You don’t need to pass the content explicitly in the controller, as the block will automatically fetch the content based on the block_id defined in the XML layout file. So, you can simplify your controller code like this:
Ensure that the Magento_Cms::block.phtml template exists and is properly rendering the block content. Normally, this template should already exist and be capable of rendering any CMS block. However, if you want custom behavior, you can create your own template and specify it in the XML.
